# Please tell me the version of RabbitMQ supported by SpringAMQP 1.7

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Please tell me the version of RabbitMQ supported by SpringAMQP 1.7.0RELEASE.
(SpringAMQP 1.7.0RELEASEがサポートするRabbitMQのVersionを教えて下さい。)

I did not understand that I saw the document.

I am using SpringBoot 1.5.1.

Comment: I used google, and:
https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/19/spring-amqp-1-7-0-release-and-1-6-7-available, so it uses amqp-client 4.0: https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2016/11/24/rabbitmq-java-client-4-0-is-released/ and about client: http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html `The client API is closely modelled on the AMQP 0-9-1 protocol specification, with additional abstractions for ease of use.`

Is it THAT hard?

Answer (score 1):

1.7.x uses the 4.0.x version of the RabbitMQ Java client, which is compatible with all 3.x versions of the broker. See the [client README on github](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client).

> Starting with 4.0, this client releases are independent from RabbitMQ server releases. These versions can still be used with RabbitMQ server 3.x.